# Ensemble classifiers (Random Forest, Bagging, Boosting, etc.) in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, classification, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I am using SSAS (SQL Server 2008 R2) to develop a classification model for a data set where 80% of values are missing. Ensemble classifiers based on trees are supposedly the best solution (Random Forest for example).

Is there any nice way of adding an ensemble classifier into SSAS? For example an [AdaBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) or any other Bagging or Boosting classifier?

I know SSAS provides plug-in functionality, but I have not come across anyone doing any ensemble solutions... Not to mention anything that you can just download and start using.

If not, is there any efficient method to connect various classifiers in SSAS? I hope I am missing something obvious that is there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the topic you are asking about, but technologically in SSAS you can register assemblies and use them in MDX. Therefore, it could be possible for you to code this in .NET and use the logic in SSAS. Please have a look at the following MSDN page for more information in case this sounds like something worth exploring.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175398.aspx

Additionally, have a look at the Data Mining SSAS provides out-of-the box as some classification objectives could be achievable by using the included algorithms:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx

Comment: Hi Boyan. Thank you for getting back to me. SSAS provides only the simplies classifiers and I was looking for something more sophisticted. There is a way of plugging in a new classifier http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176127(v=SQL.105).aspx but implementing any of the sophisticated ones is .. well .. non trivial. I was hoping for a freebie.. :)